# java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\test.csv -> C:\test2.csv: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have spring batch, here I am retrieving the files from the folder and then reading the file using OpenCV library, code is like this.

```
 List<SendingFile> sendCloudFile = new CsvToBeanBuilder<SendingFile>(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                        .withType(SendingFile.class)
                        .build()
                        .parse();
```

After that when I try to delete the same file, then it is giving me an error. (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)
What I am missing here?

```
@Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        if (stepExecution.getExitStatus().equals(ExitStatus.FAILED)) {
            service.updateErrorStatus(mailApplicationId, null, null);
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> processedFile : processedFileList.entrySet()) {
            File newFile = new File(recoveryFolder, processedFile.getKey());
            try {
                Files.move(Paths.get(processedFile.getValue()), Paths.get(recoveryFolder, processedFile.getKey()), REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.warn("Error in moving the file. ");
                log.warn(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return stepExecution.getExitStatus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1500.

The workaround is to use a different step to move the file instead of doing it in a listener.